# How to use a wildcard in Google Cloud Ops Agent configuration file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wildcard, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-ops-agent

I am using a custom configuration file for the Ops Agent to send logs from a specified path to Cloud Logging (GCP). When I am inserting the full path of a file (i.e. - *C:/nginx-1.20.2/logs/access.log*), I am able to successfully send the logs to Logging. However, when a **wildcard (*)** is used, the logs are not sent at all. I am following the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/configuration#logging-receivers) utilizing the same syntax. The system I use is a *Windows Server 2019* VM.

This is my .yaml file (using `files` as a type):

C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud Operations\Ops Agent\config\config.yaml

```
logging:
  receivers:
    nginx:
      type: files
      include_paths:
      - C:/nginx-1.20.2/logs/*.log
  processors:
    nginx:
      type: parse_json
      field: message
      time_key: time
      time_format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%L"
  service:
    pipelines:
      nginx:
        receivers: [nginx]
        processors: [nginx]
      default_pipeline:
        receivers: []
```

I am doing something wrong or this a general issue? Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I found my issue. When you want to use a wild card in Windows, the path should have the following format: **C:\nginx-1.20.2\logs\*.log** instead of C:/nginx-1.20.2/logs/*.log. Probably this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs) clarifies the log collection paths.